# Shell: Why is there a "duplicate process " on using a pipe and tee?

Tags: shell, process, pipe, tee

I'm not very familiar with bash process, and was surprised to see a "duplicate" process running while using pipe and `tee`. Can you help me understand this?

In the following, the path to the scripts is replaced by `$FOLDER`.

- `$FOLDER/DBB/myparent.ksh`:

  ```ksh
  echo "BEGIN $$ this is the parent process"
  $FOLDER/DBB/myChild.ksh
  echo "END $$ this is the parent process"
  ```
- `$FOLDER/DBB/mychild.ksh`:

  ```ksh
  function toto {
    echo " this is $$ child process "
    sleep 10
  }
  {
    echo " $$ go1 "
    toto 
    ptree $$
    echo " $$ go2 "
  } | tee myLog$$.log
  ```
- When I launch `myParent.ksh`, I have this process tree :

  ```
  28417 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd -R
    28531 -ksh
      41387 /bin/bash myParent.ksh
        41390 /bin/bash $FOLDER/DBB/myChild.ksh
          41391 /bin/bash $FOLDER/DBB/myChild.ksh
            41393 sleep 10
          41392 tee myLog41390.log
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  BEGIN 52665 this is the parent process
  in myChild.ksh
   52680 go1
   this is 52680 child process
  20192 zsched
    21104 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
      27882 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd -R
        28417 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd -R
          28531 -ksh
            52665 /bin/bash myParent.ksh
              52680 /bin/bash $FOLDER/DBB/myChild.ksh
                52688 /bin/bash $FOLDER/DBB/myChild.ksh
                  61896 ptree 52680
                52692 tee myLog52680.log
   52680 go2
  END 52665 this is the parent process
  ```

Why is there 2 `$FOLDER/DBB/myChild.ksh`?

Comment: your title states there's a duplicate PID, which is clearly not the case :p

Comment: Because the left-hand side of a pipeline runs in a subshell, which Bash implements by forking a new shell process. I'm not sure why your files are named `.ksh`, if you run them with Bash, though. (It's semi-relevant in that ksh implements subshells differently.)

Comment: Thanks,
i changed the title.
Bad habit for the .ksh i suppose, scripts are headed with "#!/bin/bash"

So if i understand correclty,  the block code at the left of pipe is ran in a subshell, 
But why is the output go 1 and go 2 is with the pid 41390 ?

I edited with complete log

Answer (score 0):

The suffix of your shell scripts is `.ksh`, but the process tree indicates they are actually being executed by the `bash` shell.

On my Debian 11, `man ksh` (which is actually `mksh`, MirBSD Korn shell) says:

> All commands of a pipeline are executed in separate subshells; this is allowed by POSIX but differs from both variants of AT&T UNIX ksh, where all but the last command were executed in subshells; see the read builtin's description for implications and workarounds.

And `man bash` says:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell). [...] If  the `lastpipe` option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin (see the description of `shopt` below), the last element of a pipeline may be run by the shell process.

So, initially process #41390 is the one started to execute `myChild.ksh`. When it sees the pipeline:

```
{
  echo " $$ go1 "
  toto 
  ptree $$
  echo " $$ go2 "
} | tee myLog$$.log
```

it will expand the `$$`'s within the pipeline, and then fork a subshell process #41391 for the compound command within `{`...`}`.

Process #41392 could be either a subshell that recognizes it only has to run a single non-internal command and just `exec()`s it as an optimization, or the `tee` command directly `fork()`+`exec()`'d by the parent #41390. In both cases it amounts to the same thing: #41392 ends up `exec()`ing something, and the `exec()` causes the command line visible to `ptree` to change.

On the other hand, the subshell #41391 has multiple commands to run, so process #41391 will keep its identity as a subshell. Since the last command it needs to execute is `echo`, a shell internal command, it will end its life as a subshell process. And because its parent #41390 already expanded the `$$`s as it was readying the pipeline for execution, the PID of subshell #41391 will never be visible in the output.